# Как узнать размер односвязного списка, указателей, элементов списка через sizeof()

Tags: c, list, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>

struct list
{
    list* next = NULL;
    float elem = 0;
} *l = new list, *k = l;

float s = 0; int q = 0;

int main()
{
    l->next = new list;
    l->next->elem = 1;
    l->next->next = new list;
    l->next->next->elem = 2;
    l->next->next->next = new list;
    l->next->next->next->elem = 3;
    l->next->next->next->next = NULL;
    



    k = l->next->next;
    l->next->next = k->next;
    delete k;
                        ;
    printf_s("%lu\n", sizeof(l->elem)); // Размер всего списка???

    for (l = l->next; l; l = l->next)
    {
        printf_s("%2.f\n", l->elem);
        s += l->elem;
        q++;
    }
    printf_s("%2.f", s / q);


    return 0 * _getch();
```

Обычно указатель в 64 битной версии занимает 8 байт
Но хочу удостоверится в этом, ну и вообще понять как работает `sizeof()`

Так-же, вопрос в размере элемента этого списка. Можно проверить так? `printf_s("%lu\n", sizeof(l->next->elem));` Если это так, то следующий вопрос, как проверить размер всех элементов списка? `printf_s("%lu\n", sizeof(l->elem));` Но компилятор мне говорит, что там 4  байта, но элементов три. Должно же быть 12? или я где-то тупой:?)

Comment: Размер односвязного списка (если он нигде не хранится) можно узнать только посчитав все элементы списка. А `elem` у вас `float` и его размер 4 байта. И это не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения к размеру списка.

Comment: Примерно... Есть функция "вес" для человека. Вы пытаетесь применить ее к очереди, причем не просто к очереди — это еще можно было бы сделать, заставив всех встать на весы (`sizeof()` от массива), но к очереди, в которой все, записав телефоны стоящего сзади, разбежались по разным местам — мол, когда подойдет моя очередь, позвоните... Так понятнее?

Comment: `new`, `delete` - по ходу, вы язык перепутали с С++.